# RVM giving me error - "line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install RVM via the terminal, and I'm getting this message. I'm not sure why. I'm not super familiar with working through the terminal. My end goal is to install jekyll for a blog. I'm trying RVM because even though I successfully installed jekyll, bash couldn't find it, so I read that RVM would help keep everything organized.

```
alexandersmbp2:~ Alex (Main)$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
/Users/Alex (Main)/.rvmrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Can you paste the offending line in .rvmrc?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing or temporarily renaming your `.rvmrc` which is apparently broken.